# Telerik UI for MVC => DateTime bug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am working with Telerik (Kendo) UI for ASP.NET MVC and I am using grid. The problem is that I have bug with DateTime type. Here source:

This is a part from my model:

```
public class Discussion
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    // More code...
}
```

This is my editor template(which comes from Telerik UI)

```
@model DateTime?

<div style="background-color: red; color: aqua; font-size: 28px;">
    @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
          .Format("MM/dd/yyyy"))
</div>
```

And in view (in grid) this is for date property:

```
columns.Bound(model => model.Date).Width(150).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
```

1. The problem is that after I create new element => http://prntscr.com/8iq7si
   in my controller I receive date with value: {1.1.0001 г. 0:00:00} => http://prntscr.com/8iq8eq
2. In very rare cases the date is send, but than there is some bug with format and ModelState is never valid.

P.S Here what is generated html:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="Date" name="Date" type="text" value="01.01.0001" data-role="datepicker" class="k-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="Date_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" data-bind="value:Date" style="width: 100%;">
```

Comment: You giving your control the name `datetimepicker` so unless you model property is named `datetimepicker` then it won't bind. Remove `.Name("datetimepicker")`

Comment: Thank you for fast response, but still the same. I am trying with [DataType(DataType.Date)] and without it. Try with Date and DateTime editor(remove .Name("") for both) and still don't bind it. => http://prntscr.com/8iqg87

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` has got nothing to do with you code (and neither does `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true`, both of which are only used by the `@Html.EditorFor()` method. And why are you setting the `Value` property? - meaning if the property already has a value then you overwrite it. Give an example of a property your binding to, and show the html your actually generating

Comment: I am using [DataType(DataType.Date)] to can use Date editor(because actyally I need DatePickerFor - not DateTimePickerFor). I am setting Value property to try set some default date(not sure for this).

Comment: Edit your question - not in comments!

Comment: The html shows the value as `value="01.01.0001"` which does not even relate to your `EditorTemplate`. Are you sure its even being hit (put a breakpoint on it to test)

Comment: It's hitted => http://prntscr.com/8iqsjw

Comment: Something else is is going on because the html your generating does not match what is generated by that template (and why do you have `.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")` on the `columns.Bound` when its already formatted?)

Comment: Trying to validate format. But even if I have it or no there is not differerence. I just cannot find where is problem with DateTime....

Comment: Give you `Date` property a value in the controller (say) `mdol.Date = DateTime.Today;` and check the `value` attribute - it should be `value="9/21/2015"`

Comment: Not exactly => http://prntscr.com/8is2uo, http://prntscr.com/8is35y

Comment: OMG. Why are you specifying a date format that is clearly not the same is the culture on your server! If you want to do that, then you will need to create a custom `ModelBinder`

Comment: So you say to remove all format and use it like it is default?

Comment: Either that, or if you want to use the `MM/dd/yyyy` format either set the culture in your `web.config` file i.e. `<system.web><globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />` or create a custom `ModelBinder` to convert the date to your current culture.

Comment: Ok, but now I tried to remove all data anotations and use default(server culture) and than I get: on => http://prntscr.com/8isbqn => http://prntscr.com/8isbu1 and on => http://prntscr.com/8isbyd => http://prntscr.com/8isc1z and that was reason why I started modify formats. I don't need some special format, but just it's not accepting default one.

Comment: If you don't change the format on the server, you will still need to change the format in the view to match your server format because the default is `MM/dd/yyyy` - (I don't know what that is but it has a `.` as the date separator - `MM.dd.yyyy`

Comment: And how can I change format in view? If in the view format is with `/` in controller I still receive it with `.`. And if I give for example: `9/12/2015` in view I receive `{9.12.2015 г. 0:00:00}`, but if I have `9/13/2015` than I receive `{1.1.0001 г. 0:00:00}`. There is just some problem with `MM/dd` or `dd/MM` I am not sure.

Comment: That suggests its `dd/MM` not `MM/dd` (I  don't know what culture your using)

Comment: The culture is `bg-BG`. But actually I have no claims what will be the culture. I just want to import the datetime in database, no matter is it `09/30/2015` or `30/09/2015`, etc. Just want to pass `ModelState`, but still cannot make it.

Comment: There is no bug. Its you code that's wrong. You need to pass the value to the server in the format that matches your server culture.

Comment: Ok, but how can I pass the value in correct server culture. I am trying to change kendo culture so It will be passed correct, but I am not sure how exactly to change it.

Comment: Forget the Kendo controls for the moment. You should always start with the basics. Just create a view with a textbox for a date and see how it works and binds in the POST method.

Comment: I don't understand how that simple form will help me in current case. I am working with kendo, so... I tried also to do something like:
`@{
        var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString();
    }
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cultures/kendo.culture." + culture + ".min.js")"></script>
    <script>kendo.culture("@culture"); </script>` 
and the result is the same..